# Parsing the dictionary key concatenating list's two items in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

#### How do I parse a dictionary value concatenating two words as key from a list of words?

I want to search this dictionary to see if it has a key matching from the items of a list. The "words" list is a user input that I split so I can't change it to words = ["third dict"]

```
words = ["hello", "hi", "first", "morning", "dict", "third", "seconddict"]

groups = {
    "firstdict": {
        "one": "first dict #1",
        "two": "first dict #2",
        "three": "first dict #3",
        "four": "first dict #4"
    },
    "seconddict": {
        "one": "second dict #1",
        "two": "second dict #2",
        "three": "second dict #3",
        "four": "second dict #4",
        "five": "second dict #5",
        "six": "second dict #6"
    },
    "third dict":{
        "one": "third dict #1",
        "two": "third dict #2",
        "three": "third dict #3",
        "four": "third dict #4",
        "five": "third dict #5"
    }
}
```

I can use this to get what's inside the dictionary with one worded keys

```
for word in words:
    if word in groups:
        print(groups[word])
```

which prints

```
{'one': 'first dict #1', 'two': 'first dict #2', 'three': 'first dict #3', 'four': 'first dict #4'}
{'one': 'second dict #1', 'two': 'second dict #2', 'three': 'second dict #3', 'four': 'second dict #4', 'five': 'second dict #5', 'six': 'second dict #6'}
```

How do I use the list "words" to search the dictionary for the key "third dict" and have it print this

```
{'one': 'third dict #1', 'two': 'third dict #2', 'three': 'third dict #3', 'four': 'third dict #4', 'five': 'third dict #5'}
```

Comment: Can you use a proper example, where you can define all the first, second and third dicts. And also give the desired output for that example.

Comment: Your problem is not clear well. Please elaborate clearly and give your expected output.

Comment: I think I edited it so its more clear now.

Comment: just used words with "third word" in it ```words = ["third dict"]```

Comment: Sorry this was just an example. I know that it would work if I did that. But what actually happens is it's a user input that I split into that list. So I have to somehow find the key that has two matching words from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you out.

**Modified code**

```
for word1 in words:
    for word2 in words:
        if word1 + ' ' + word2 in groups:
            print(groups[word1 + ' ' + word2])
```

**Output**

```
{'one': 'third dict #1', 'two': 'third dict #2', 'three': 'third dict #3', 'four': 'third dict #4', 'five': 'third dict #5'}
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect! Thank you! Now would it be possible for it to print "seconddict" as well since that's also in the words list?

Comment: You are welcome. Please place an upvote and accept my question as your answer using the tick button. Thank you.